# Use of DynamicFunction in Dynamic LinQ-Query throws exxception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

i do have a sample-program:

- Using .Net 5.0
- Using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.10
- Using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core 1.2.18
- I adapt the sample from https://dynamic-linq.net/advanced-entityframework
- i have the following program:

  ```
       static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
       try
       {
           DataContext ctx = new DataContext();
           var config = new ParsingConfig { ResolveTypesBySimpleName = true, };
           List<Customer> customers3 = ctx.Customers.Where(config, "DynamicFunctions.Like(Lastname,\"test%\")").ToList();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Exception:{e}");
       }
   }
  ```

When i run this program i get the exception: Enum type 'DynamicFunctions' not found (at index 21)

Can anyone help?

best regards

Volkhard

Comment: As mentioned in the link, reference some of the [EF Core specific packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq/5.2.18) instead of `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

Comment: Hello Ivan,
thanks for your hint - the problem still exists. 
And if i don´t reference System.Linq.Dynamic.Core i can´t use a string in the where-clause.

Comment: @VolkhardVogeler Have you got any solution for the above problem? I struck with the same problem.